# Azure Mobile Service; inserting to another table & call 'insert' script?

Tags: javascript, insert, crud, azure-mobile-services

I am using a 'virtual' table to insert batches of objects into the database. However, when I initialize the table object and call insert/update on it, I am not inserting through the designated Azure Mobile Service 'INSERT' script for that table. Is there a neat way to call the insert script of another table other than creating another mobile service request (Which I want to avoid given the already high amount of requests I am getting)? Or do I need to move the validation functionality to the de-batching of the objects?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported, but there's an open issue in the [MobileServices UserVoice page](http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/) which addresses exactly this scenario - http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/4180025-support-crud-table-scripts-via-the-js-table-object. Please vote it up if you want to raise the visibility to the team.